# JNI Native Method causing VM crashing

Tags: java, c++, function, java-native-interface

I'm implementing a Java method as Native in C++

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL myMethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass, //parameters){

    int** result = //my function to obtain a matrix n x m of integers
    std::vector<jint> tmp;

    //fill the vector tmp with matrix integers and deallocate the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            tmp[m*i + j] = result[i][j];
        }
        free(result[i]);
    }
    free(result);

    jintArray jResults = env->NewIntArray( tmp.size() );
    env->SetIntArrayRegion( jResults, 0, tmp.size(), &tmp[0] );
    return env->NewObjectArray(tmp.size(), env->GetObjectClass(jResults), 0);
}
```

It compiles fine and java loads the dll successfully. But i get this error at runtime:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x10009a7d, pid=2264, tid=3856
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [myDLL.dll+0x9a7d]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as: hs_err_pid2264.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
Java result 1
```

Any idea?

Comment: What is the Java declaration of the function? Is it supposed to return an int[][] full of nulls, (because that's what you create in the return statement)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code as I'm writing this:

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL myMethod(JNIEnv *env, jclass, //parameters){

    int** result = //my function to obtain a matrix n x m of integers
    std::vector<jint> tmp;

    //fill the vector tmp with matrix integers and deallocate the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            tmp[m*i + j] = result[i][j];
        }
        free(result[i]);
    }
    free(result);

    jintArray jResults = env->NewIntArray( tmp.size() );
    env->SetIntArrayRegion( jResults, 0, tmp.size(), &tmp[0] );
    return env->NewObjectArray(tmp.size(), env->GetObjectClass(jResults), 0);
}
```

In this code you're accessing various elements of a zero-size vector `tmp`.

A `std::vector` is not an associative array; it's an ordinary contiguous array. Hence you need to either size it up front, or use the `push_back` method to add new elements. You can specify a size like this:

```
std::vector<jint> tmp( m*n );
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: thank you :) i'm new to c++, i'm mostly a java developer.
finally now i get a result from the java side, but it is null! i think that the return command has an error too

Comment: it's over a decade since i did JNI stuff, but the impression i have from looking at the code is that the `return` expression creates an array of all nulls, and that you maybe should instead return `jResults`. :-)

Comment: sorry about last comment, looking at the return type it seems my impression was wrong. but somehow you need to get those values over to the returned array object.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the `result` variable, so your code ends up trying to read from garbage addresses, and then trying to free pointers it has read from a garbage address.

*(Oh, never mind, there was hidden code...)*

Comment: i obtain the value for that variable from a function that returns an `int**`

Comment: No such obtaining is going on in the code you quote in the question. (Ah, was there something interesting being replaced with a comment? Then how are we supposed to be able to help you?)

Comment: i replaced that function with a comment because my problem is not related with that function. that function simply returns an `int**` and it works fine

Comment: hey man, do you want the entire project? that function is very complex, i can't paste it here... you just don't need it if you want to help me to solve this problem because it works

Answer (score 0):

I have my doubts regarding whether you can return an int[] as an object array. In particular the line `env->GetObjectClass(jResults)` seems suspicious to me. This line tries to get the class for int[], which is one which doesn't exist to my knowledge. My suggestion are to either return an Integer[], and to thereby get the class by using env->GetObjectClass("java/lang/Integer), or change the method signature to jintArray.  As far as i know, jintArray != jobjectArray.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the Java VM option -Xcheck:jni. The detail can be found at [www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtq](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtq).